# Как создать циклом, переменные?

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки, функции, циклы

```js
let name = "Bred";

   function getEachNameSymbol(name) {
    for (let i = 0; i < name.length; ++i){
        let arr = [{
          i = name[i]
        }]
        return arr;
    }
}

console.log(getEachNameSymbol(name))

}
```

Хочу реализовать через массив объектов, подскажите как правильно это сделать.

Comment: то есть чтобы в каждой итерации создавалсья новая переменная?

Comment: Да, или сделать коллекцию из символов

Comment: Вы хотите получить массив символов из строки?

Comment: @Komdosh , да а если не массив то столько переменных сколько символов в строке

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам нужно получать каждый элемент отдельно и в порядке очереди вы можете воспользоваться встроенным итератором.

```js
let name = "Bred";

let iterator = name[Symbol.iterator]();

for (var letter of iterator) {
  console.log(letter)
}
```

Comment: Ого какая дичь оказывается в JS есть

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, чисто теоретически, строка в JS имеет многие свойства массива, но если вам нужен именно массив то можно поступить так:

```js
let name = "Bred";
const nameArr = name.split('');
console.log(nameArr);
```

Ну окей, через цикл:

```js
let name = "Bred";
const nameArr = [];
for(let i = 0; i<name.length; ++i){
   nameArr.push(name[i]);
}

console.log(nameArr);
```

Comment: мне нужно через цикл это сделать, так задание стоит